# Checklist with float images in the left side of the page

Tags: graphics, positioning

I want to create a document which is mainly a check list, but what I want is to show an image on the left side of the page, and the check list was shown in the right side of the page. Like the image below:

[image: the blue rectangle refer to the image, there are arrows in the images to associated with each check list items]

My question is, what is the way to do this in LaTeX, I have read some discussions about `multicols` package, but it does not support float images.

**Question**:
Now, I modify your code a little to create a landscape page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth} %minipage's width
\raisebox{-.94\textheight}{%
\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}
}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1em}\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.\hspace{.5em}}p{.45\textwidth}c@{}}
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large\bfseries Check list}\\[.5em]
   This is first item to be checked & $\square$\\
   This is second item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$\\
   This is third item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$\\
   This is fourth item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$\\
   This is fifth item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$\\
   This is sixth item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But I see the generated pdf have two pages, the first page is empty, I'm not sure why?

**Another question 1**: What does the line `@{\hspace{1em}\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.\hspace{.5em}}p{.45\textwidth}c@{}` is used for, I don't know, I guess this is used to align the table with the `minipage`, but I don't know why.

**Another question 2**: Why do you use a `\raisebox{-.94\textheight}`, if I remove this, I see the image can still show there, but the check list items will go to the right bottom side of the image.

**EDIT**: Two images added (before and after of removing the line containing the `raisebox` command)

[image: The image before remove of the raisebox line]

[image: The image after I remove the raisebox line]

Comment: Do you need wrapped floating images?

Comment: Hi, thanks, what do you mean by wrapped floating images? In my case, the images is always in the left column(the image should not be higher than one page), and the checklist is always in the right column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\raisebox{-.94\textheight}{%
\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}
}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1em}\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.\hspace{.5em}}p{.55\textwidth}c@{}}
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large\bfseries Check list}\\[.5em]
   This is first item to be checked & $\square$\\
   This is second item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$
\end{tabular}
\clearpage %% second page
\noindent
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\raisebox{-.94\textheight}{%
\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}
}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1em}\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.\hspace{.5em}}p{.55\textwidth}c@{}}
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large\bfseries Check list}\\[.5em]
   This is first item to be checked & $\square$\\
   This is second item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## update to answer the edited question:

> But I see the generated pdf have two pages, the first page is empty, I'm not sure why?

It is because you have lowered the picture too much. you have to adjust the dimensions in

```
\raisebox{-.82\textheight}{%    %% look out the changes
```

Also, it is appropriate to use `scale` here. Use the options to `\includegraphics` judiciously.

> what does the line @{\hspace{1em}\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.\hspace{.5em}}p{.45\textwidth}c@{} used for, I don't know, I guess this is used to align the table with the minipage, but I don't know why.

I tried to put the number here. The two `\hspace` commands keep the numbers away from the picture and the text. I used `p` column type so the the text wraps at the end of line. The last `@{}` removes the `tabcolsep` (the gap between two columns) after the last column.

> why you use a \raisebox{-.94\textheight}, if I remove this, I see the image can still show there, but the check list items will go the the right bottom side of the image.

You got it right. It is used to align the list items at the top of the picture which is wanted.

Hope things are clear now. Happy TeXing. :-)

Corrected new MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\newcounter{rowno}
\setcounter{rowno}{0}
\begin{document}
\noindent
{\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth} %minipage's width
\raisebox{-.82\textheight}{%
\includegraphics[width=.95\linewidth,height=\textheight]{example-image}
}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{tabular}{@{\hspace{1em}\stepcounter{rowno}\therowno.\hspace{.5em}}p{.5\textheight}c@{}}
   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\large\bfseries Check list}\\[.5em]
   This is first item to be checked & $\square$\\
   This is second item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$\\
   This is third item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$\\
   This is fourth item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$\\
   This is fifth item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$\\
   This is sixth item to be checked and this sentence is going to the second line & $\square$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please adjust the dimensions in

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
```

and

```
\raisebox{-.94\textwidth}{%
```

and

```
  p{.8\textheight}
```

suitably until you get what makes you happy.

Comment: Hi, Harish Kumar, many thanks for your answer, it looks very well. Firstly, I try to put the image and all the check list item in a table, but I have an issue that the image will always expand to the combined table cell, see: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138892/how-to-automatically-set-the-hight-of-the-combined-cell-when-using-multirow-pack, I think you method can totally avoid the multirow issue. Thanks again!

Comment: @ollydbg23 `multirow` is hard to mend in that aspect. In my approach, you can create second page also.

Comment: Hi, Harish, thanks, I just drop the way to use multirow, now I still have some questions about your answer, I have updated my original question, I hope you can give me some hint. Sorry, I'm just a latex beginner, but I have some c/c++ programming experience, so i just treat latex a programming language.

Comment: @ollydbg23 No problem. See the update.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I see the new code your supplied, works great. Though I still not fully understand all the Latex (code) syntax you write, I'm reading some Latex books now.