# How to automatically set the height of the combined cell when using multirow package

Tags: tables, multirow

Here is the simplified code to demonstrate my issue:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline 
 &  & \\
\hline 
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{\rule{3cm}{4cm}} &  & \\
\cline{2-3} 
 &  & \\
\hline 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Now, the result table is below, you see the big black figure is not fit in the cell.
[image: big cell in multirow mode]

How to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to display a picture next to some cells? In this case you should have a look at his [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/138899/31058). If not could add some explanation about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, Ludovic, thanks, the link you give is the original question I post, I first try to put all the picture and check list item in a table, but it was not quite easy. So, I try to use another way, manually put a minipage and table, and put the two together.

Comment: So should you remove this question or do you still want an answer for this case (which you should maybe clarify by editing your question)?

Comment: Hi, Ludovic, I still think the ability to control the combined row's height is necessary, so I'm still waiting for a method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checklist with float images in the left side of the page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138882/checklist-with-float-images-in-the-left-side-of-the-page)